# POST en React native con axios no funciona

Tags: php, react-native, axios

Tengo duda en porque a la hora de querer postear con axios en mi php no recibe las variables que le envio y solo actualiza la tabla de mi phpmyAdmin con valores vacios, aqui el codigo de react:

```
subirPuntaje(){
  axios.post('http://miIP/marcador/guardarDatos.php',{
        nombres: this.props.navigation.state.params.usuario,
        puntajes: this.state.puntaje
  })
  .then(response=>{
    console.log('¡Tabla Actualizada!');
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Y el codigo de PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'conexion.php';

$nombre = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombres');
$puntaje = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'puntajes');

$sql="INSERT INTO guardar_marcador(nombre,puntaje) VALUES ('$nombre','$puntaje')";

?>
```

Comment: ¿Da algún error? ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en el servidor? ¿Depuraste los valores `this.props.navigation.state.params.usuario` y `this.state.puntaje` en el cliente?

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes de validar que los datos están llegando a tu server con un

`var_dump($_POST);`

Podrás ver la respuesta desde las herramientas del navegador sección "Network", por ultimo si estas usando `filter_input` debes pasarle un tercer parametro **FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS** de lo contrario por defecto tomara **FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW** que no te va a satinizar los valores.